# Determine a JDK install directory through Python

Tags: python, path, directory, java

I'm currently writing a program in Python, and I would like to determine the path to the JDK install directory if it's on the system.  Is there a way of doing this in Python?  If not, is there a way of doing it in Java (or another language)?  If it is the latter, I could open a subprocess from within Python to obtain it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME system variables. But there is no guarantee that there are no other JDKs installed. You have to be more specific what you are willing to achieve.

Comment: How come those variables do not exist on my system, even though I have the JDK installed?

Comment: @Alty, these are 'system variables'. These are either set or not. Installation may or may not set them by default.

Comment: OK, thanks, well that's pretty problematic then. I'm assuming that means there's no way to know for sure if/where it's installed then.

Comment: @Alty, If you're on Windows and a proper Windows installer were used, there is a chance you can find information in registry.